# How can I put an @Html tag like editorfor inside an input with type email?

Tags: c#, html, sql, visual-studio-2012

Why cant i just put the input around my @Html.EditorFor like this

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
</input>
```

what im trying to do is to bind(?) the email field to my database.

tried this:

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email"
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
>
```

This works in some way, but the > tag shows up on the webpage.

any tips on how I can solv this?

Comment: Not sure I understand - `@Html.EditorFor` **is** an input... As it's part of your model, it will be submitted with the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the html attributes you want on your editorFor field like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" } })
```

You don't want an input form around your EditorFor.